# Holding number of strings

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a concordance.
I have a dictionary where are each word and frequency of appearing  this word in text.
Now I would have to store a number of line where word occured.
To do it I suppose to make a container which will store each line.
 Something like this:

```
List<String> eachLine = new List<string>();
                using (var strReader = new StreamReader(@"pathToFile/Text.txt"))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = strReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                        eachLine.Add(line);
                    }
                }
```

Here are Dictionary

```
 Dictionary<string, int> concordanceDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        string lines = File.ReadAllText(path:Text.txt").ToLower();

        string[] words = SplitWords(lines);

        foreach (var  word in words)
        {
            int i = 1;
            if (!concordanceDictionary.ContainsKey(word))
            {
                concordanceDictionary.Add(word, i);

            }
            else
            {
                concordanceDictionary[word]++;
            }

        }
        var list =concordanceDictionary.Keys.ToList();
        list.Sort();
```

To store number of lines I'll create a 'List' where I  will put index of line where word occured by using method Contain for each word in dictionary  which will check if this word is in

```
   ' List<String> eachLine '
```

The problem is how to display  each word   with list of number of line?
May be you can suggest me more elegant and easier way to do it

Comment: Making a class that stores that information and a dictionary to keep track of it is much easier IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a console app for you to run

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ReadTextToDictionary read = new ReadTextToDictionary();

            var strings = read.TextToListString(@"C:\stackoverflow\first.txt");

            var dictionarys = read.TextToDictionaryString(@"C:\stackoverflow\second.txt");
            foreach(var s in strings) {
                var compare = dictionarys.Where(a=>a.Value.Contains(s.ToString()));
                foreach(var f in compare)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s+" in line "+f.Key.ToString() + " " + f.Value);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class ReadTextToDictionary
    {
        public List<string> TextToListString(string path){

            var lines =  System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);

            return lines.ToList();
        }

        public Dictionary<int,string> TextToDictionaryString(string path)
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> dstr = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
            int count = 0;
            foreach (var s in lines)
            {
                count++;
                dstr.Add(count, s);
            }

            return dstr;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `Dictionary<String,List<Int32>>` where the key is `String` which is the current word, and the `List<Int32>` is the list of line-numbers the word appears on. To get the occurrence count just dereference the list's `Count` property: `dictionary[ word ].Count`.

As an aside, you don't need to read everything into memory at once (as `String[]` instances). You can simply read through the file character-by-character and identify whitespace and line-breaks.

To that end, this is my implementation:

```
void Run() {

    Dictionary< String, List<Int32> > dict = new Dictionary< String, List<Int32> >();

    foreach(Tuple<String,Int32> wordOccurrence in GetWords()) {
        String word = wordOccurrence.Item1;
        Int32 line = wordOccurrence.Item2;
        if( !dict.ContainsKey( word  ) ) dict.Add( word , new List<Int32>() );
        dict[ word ].Add( line );
    }

    foreach(String word in dict.Keys) {

        Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\" appeared {1} times, on these lines:", word, dict[word].Count);
        foreach(Int32 line in dict[word]) Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", line );
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}

IEnumerable< Tuple<String,Int32> > GetWords() {

    using(StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader("fileName")) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Int32 nc; Char c;
        Itn32 lineNumber = 0;
        while( (nc = rdr.Read() != -1 ) {
            c = (Char)nc;

            if( Char.IsWhitespace(c) ) {
                if( sb.Length > 0 ) {
                    yield return new Tuple( sb.ToString(), lineNumber );
                    sb.Length = 0;
                }
                if( c == '\n' ) lineNumber++;
            } else {
                sb.Append( c );
            }
        }
        if( sb.Length > 0 ) yield return new Tuple( sb.ToString(), lineNumber );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to store each line where the word occurs in a list, as the value portion of a dictionary with the word as a key.

In otherwords, you would have a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` where the key is a word and the associated list is all the lines containing the word.

This way, you can quickly access the lines AND you get the number of occurrences for free (`dict[someWord].Count;`)

For example:

```
// words dictionary has a word key and a list of lines containing the word
var words = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

using (var strReader = new StreamReader(@"pathToFile/Text.txt"))
{
    string line;

    // Read each line
    while ((line = strReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // Get each word from the line
        var wordsInLine = line.ToLower().Split(' ');

        foreach (var word in wordsInLine)
        {
            // If this word already exists, update it's line number
            if (words.ContainsKey(word))
            {
                words[word].Add(line);
            }
                // Otherwise, add a new word with this line number to the list
            else
            {
                words.Add(word, new List<string> {line});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if you really wanted to get all the lines, you could either add them to a list in the loop above, or do something like this:

```
var allLines = words.SelectMany(w => w.Value).Distinct().ToList();
```