# How to get number of line(not ammount) for each word where this word occured

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make concordance.
I need to get number of lines where word occured.
To do it I decided to read each line  and then check if word in dictionary is in this line, if yes - remember index of line and pass this index to list
But if in  one line are  two  words which are the same I don't need  showing index of this line  two times.
What is the best way to do it?

```
  public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> concordanceDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Text.txt");

        string myText =
            File.ReadAllText(path: @"C:Text.txt").ToLower();

        string[] words = SplitWords(myText);

        foreach (var  word in words)
        {
            int i = 1;
            if (!concordanceDictionary.ContainsKey(word))
            {
                concordanceDictionary.Add(word, i);

            }
            else
            {
                concordanceDictionary[word]++;
            }

        }
        var list = concordanceDictionary.Keys.ToList();
        list.Sort();



        foreach (var key in list)
        {
            List<int> numberOfLine = new List<int>();
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                if (line.Contains(key))
                {
                    int m = IndexOf(line);
                    numberOfLine.Add(m);
                }


                Console.WriteLine("{0}.........: {1}....{2}", key, concordanceDictionary[key], numberOfLine);
            }
        }
    }

    static string[] SplitWords(string s)
        {
            return Regex.Split(s, @"\W+");
        }
}
```

and here is a promblem

```
int m = IndexOf(line);
numberOfLine.Add(m);
```

How to  get number of lines for each word in dictionary?

This is my previous post: [Holding number of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580037/holding-number-of-strings)
 There are any way to solve it but I'm too novice in C# and there is some things which I don't understand. I would be happy if you could explain in more detail

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? Can you reproduce the error?

Comment: That's not an error. An error is the message given by the compiler before runtime or the exception data in the Output Window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the kind of issue that's made significantly easier by making your own class, rather than trying to force your use case into the built-in objects and/or juggling separate collections that have to keep index parity.

I would start by making a WordInfo object:

```
public class WordInfo
{
    public WordInfo(string word, int firstLineNumber)
    {
        this.Word = word;
        this.WordCount = 1;
        this.LineNumbers = new List<int>() { firstLineNumber };
    }

    public string Word { get; set; }
    public int WordCount { get; set; }
    public List<int> LineNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

And then you could have your concordanceDictionary object be a Dictionary of string, WordInfo:

```
Dictionary<string, WordInfo> concordanceDictionary = new Dictionary<string, WordInfo>();

int i = 1;
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\Text.txt"))
{
    foreach (string word in SplitWords(line).ToLower())
    {
        if (!concordanceDictionary.ContainsKey(word))
        {
            concordanceDictionary.Add(word, new WordInfo(word, i));
        }
        else
        {
            concordanceDictionary[word].WordCount++;
            if (!concordanceDictionary[word].LineNumbers.Contains(i))
            {
                concordanceDictionary[word].LineNumbers.Add(i);
            }
        }
    }

    i++;
}
```

Then, if you still want to sort the WordInfo objects:

```
List<WordInfo> sortedWordInfos = concordanceDictionary.Values.OrderByDescending(a => a.WordCount).ToList();
```

Comment: There are errors:    'int' does not contain a definition for 'WordCount' and no extension method 'WordCount' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) and "The method 'Add' has two parametres but is invoked  with 1 agrument"

Comment: Try this again now - I fixed a couple typos.

Comment: Thanks, but "Cannot resolve symbol WordCount" in the last line

Comment: Can you make sure it's spelled correctly? It looks like there was a typo in the sorting line that read "WordCOunt" instead of "WordCount."

Comment: of course  I changed it. When I'm writing "a." intelesens doesn't give a hint. There wasn't WordCount

Comment: My mistake - I'd accidentally copied concordanceDictionary.Keys... rather than concordanceDictionary.Values. Try with the updated code above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63809/discussion-between-cherry-and-furkle).

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to instead build an occurrence list from the text and then complete your concordance using it. You could do all that in two lines of LINQ:

```
        var lines = new []{ "This is line one and", "this is line two"};
        var concordance = new[]{"and", "line", "this", "two", "foo"}
            .Select(x => x.ToLower()).ToList();

        var occurrences = lines
            .SelectMany((line, i) =>
                line.Split(' ')
                   .Distinct()
                   .Select(w => new { name = w, index = i + 1 }))
            .ToLookup(w => w.name.ToLower(), w => w.index);

        var all = concordance
            .Select(w => w + " : " + string.Join(", ", occurrences[w]));

        foreach (var r in all)    // or first or all
            Console.WriteLine(r);
```

The key item to ensure each word on a line only gets in once is the `Distinct` call. Note also how you can put an index in a `Select` or `SelectMany` call.